# Add WCF web service to web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I am a little confused by web services and how they're used. I have created a WCF web service that has an operation contract taking 3 parameters. Then I interrogate our database and return an object matching the data contract. All seems to be good. But how does a third party use our web service? What do I need to provide to them in order for them to use it? Do I need to put a link on my web site? What should that link look like? Thanks!

Comment: couple of reading suggestions: [How to consume Wcf Service in javascript](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/979a1df7-7e04-45d6-92bb-6a9ee614941c/how-to-consume-wcf-service-in-javascript?forum=wcf), [Consuming a WCF Service in Java Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/consuming-a-wcf-service-in-java-application/), and the [python, for example](https://www.google.com/search?q=consuming+wcf+from+javascript&oq=consuming+wcf+from+javascript&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=consuming+wcf+from+python)

Answer (score 0):

For third party, you need to share:

1. **Path of Hosted service**: it is needed to add service reference.
2. **Information about Service Contract methods**: documentation of what exposed operation contracts actually do.
3. **DataContract dll**: **`Only`** if you are **`reusing`** DataContracts.
4. Some information some times needed to add endpoint if you have to customize default endpoint for client (something like service timeout, packet size etc).

Hope it helps.